# Тень внутри текста

Tags: html, css, css3

Вот макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML

```
<h1>ВНЖ ДУБАЙ под ключ на 2 года</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 {  
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Получается текст только белым шрифтом. Нужно сделать тень внутри текста. Как это сделать? Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

В виду большого объёма исходных данных в вопросе, получилось следующее:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

h1.clip {
  font: 900 8vw/1.2 sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0.06em 0.025em #0008);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

h1.clip div {
  padding: 0.083em 0;
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#000, #000), linear-gradient(#000, #000);
  -webkit-mask-clip: text, padding-box;
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
  mask-composite: exclude;
  background-color: #57545d;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="clip"><div>ВНЖ ДУБАЙ под ключ на 2 года</div></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте что то вроде этого , может если поиграться с цветами поможет.

```
        h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
        background-color: #565656;
        color: transparent;
        text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.981);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -moz-background-clip: text;
        background-clip: text;
    }
```

Comment: Не получилось. Текс получился размазанным.